# Menu at the bottom of the viewport then stick to the top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve [something like this](http://conheca.unitfour.com.br/intouch) (100% height background picture with menu at the bottom) but can't figure out how get there.

My issue is that no matter where I include `<div class="main-menu">` in the HTML code, it becomes either invisible or not placed where it should... See [my jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ETvvY/).

Or another and better option maybe would be to have the background picture taking 100% of the viewport height minus 50px (the height of the menu)?

Thanks for your help

**CSS**

```
html,body{height: 100%} 

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font: 300 1em/1.38 'Open Sans';
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
}

header {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  z-index: 12;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
}

.element {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.element-1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 8;
  border-top: 10px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/800/800?image=1');
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: rgb(222, 222, 222);
}
.main-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #358acb;
    position: absolute;
    color: #000;
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <header>
    <div class="element element-1"></div>

  </header>  
  <p class="logo">LOGO</p>
  <article>  <div class="main-menu">This will be the menu</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bottom:0px;
    left: 0;
    z-index:20;If I understood correctly, this should fix your problem and then of course some styling needed.

```
.main-menu {
   width: 100%;
   height: 50px;
   background: #358acb;
   position: absolute;
   color: #000;
   bottom:0px;
   left: 0;
   z-index:20;
 }
```

See [***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/ETvvY/2/)